# Custom date picker looks bad on large device

Tags: android, xml, android-datepicker

I created a simple custom date picker in xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/datePickerLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <DatePicker
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mDatePicker"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:spinnersShown="true"
        android:calendarViewShown="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

It looks well on a small device, but on a large one (tablet) it looks like this:

[image]

The window is much bigger that it needs to be, even though I set the width and height of the date picker to wrap_content. What can I do to make the content of the date picker to fill its window? I also tried to change the text size by applying a custom theme but it didn't solve it

In case it matters, here is the custom dialog builder I'm using to create the custom date picker:

```
 val mCustomDatePicker = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_date_picker, activityStageOne, false)

        val mDatePicker = mCustomDatePicker.findViewById(R.id.mDatePicker) as DatePicker
        mDatePicker.maxDate = (Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime())
//        mDatePicker.maxDate = (y)

        val mDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        mDialog.setView(mCustomDatePicker)

        addListenersForEditText()


        mDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", object : DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
            override fun onClick( dialog: DialogInterface, which: Int) {
                ageET.clearFocus()
                val mCalendar  = Calendar.getInstance()
                mCalendar.set(mDatePicker.year, mDatePicker.month, mDatePicker.dayOfMonth)

                val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat(DATE_PATTERN)
                try {
                    age = dateFormat.format(mCalendar.time)
                } catch (e: ParseException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }

                ageET.setText((mDatePicker.month + 1).toString() + " / " + mDatePicker.dayOfMonth.toString() + " / " + mDatePicker.year.toString())
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", object: DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
            @Override
            override fun onClick( dialog: DialogInterface, which: Int) {
                ageET.clearFocus()
                dialog.dismiss()
            }
        })


        mDialog.create()
```

I also tried as Md suggested, to refer to a custom theme like in styles.xml:

```
<resources>

<style name="Theme.Dialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog" />

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/alegreya</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Action bar application theme. -->
    <style name="AppThemeActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/alegreya</item>
    </style>
```

But when referring to it in the builder:

```
val mDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.Theme_Dialog)
```

I'm getting the error 'unresolved reference' as if Theme_Dialog cannot be found

Comment: You want to fill it in screen?

Comment: To fill the window, thanks

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear

Comment: Have you tried applying match-parent to datepicker?

Comment: Yes, in that case it still doesn't fit the window and is not centered, it goes to the left and on the right there is more space

Comment: But date-picker only looks good in the dialog form, so do you want to achieve any special feature with design like this? Otherwise please use date-picker with dialog format because that looks good.

Comment: I have to use the custom one, to acheive the feature of blocking future dates

Comment: You can block future dates with dialog format as well

Comment: Can you add your code where you use the layout?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `dialog` theme in your `AlertDialog` when you initialize it. Check below:

```
val mDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.Theme_Dialog)
```

Add this style in your `styles.xml`

```
<style name="Theme.Dialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog" />
```

**Or**

```
<style name="Theme.Dialog" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Dialog" />
```

**Output in Tablet:**

[image]

Comment: Ok but what should I put in this custom theme so that the content fits the window? Thanks

Comment: Oh I see that it is only supported from API version 21? Is it possible to solve the problem for versions >= 18 ?

Comment: Hey Md thank you but it's not working I did exactly as you instructed, but I cannot refer to that theme from within the builder, I'm putting the second parameter as "R.style.Theme_Dialog" but getting an error "unresolved reference", even though the custom theme exists in styles.xml like you wrote. Why could it be happening? Thank you

Comment: Can you add your `styles.xml` and if possible then screenshot of error?

Comment: Yes I updated my question to include it thank you very much

Comment: You didn't try my style. Please use `<style name="Theme.Dialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog" />` and also place it in your default `styles.xml`

Comment: Here I did try your style exactly as your wrote, the problem is that within the builder it cannot be recognized. I'm still getting "unresolved reference" when setting the parameter R.style.Theme_Dialog

Comment: Not yet but I will try to and then ask again thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use match parent instead wrap_content

```
<DatePicker
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my research for TimePicker you should use scale for transform size... Try that and be aware of responsive!

fE.

```
 android:scaleX="23dp"
 android:scaleY="23dp"
```

Comment: I'm getting an error "'300dp' is incompatible with attribute scaleX (attr) float"